# Why do I get "An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80004005'" when building a setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

Why do I get the following error when building a setup project?

> An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80004005'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both of the reasons I found are already in other answers, but they are in separate answers and not fully explained. So, hopefully this will combine the possibilities and give good means of debugging each. :)

**Common Reason**

My problem was not a dependency error. However, that does seem to be the common reason. So, basically, you need to check your [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file and make sure that all dependencies are still valid. Probably the best blog response on how you can easily resolve this if it is a dependency issue is *[An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80004005'](http://tech-trinkets.blogspot.com/2010/03/error-occurred-while-validating-hresult.html)*.

*Extract from blog*:

> Follow steps below to troubleshoot.
>
> - If you have multiple project outputs in your solution, identify the project that is giving the problem. You can do that by removing one project at a time from the Setup Project(S) until error goes away.
> - Once project is identified, identify the reference that could be giving the problem.
>
>   - Check if the project(A) is referencing to a project that has been removed from solution. - Remove such references if any.
>   - Check if the Project(A) is referencing to a project that was moved to a diffenrent physical location after it was added as a reference. - Remove and add such references.
> - Rebuild setup project after fixing the reference accordingly to see if error goes away.

**Alternative Reason**

My problem had to do with Visual Studio versioning, however. So, if your dependencies are valid and you still are getting this problem, then you resolve this if it is a problem with VS2010 .

Basically, if you run [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) and see this warning:

> Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0", which is not supported by
>   this version of MSBuild. Treating the project as if it had
>   ToolsVersion="3.5"

Then the problem is Visual Studio versioning. This means that one project was opened or created in Visual Studio 2010 and then saved or added to an existing 3.5 solution. I simply searched all files in my project for `ToolsVersion="4.0"` and found the offending `.csproj` file, opened it in a text editor and manually changed the `4.0` to a `3.5`.

Answer (score 21):

One project in solution had `ToolsVersion="4.0"` (in .csproj file), changed it to `ToolsVersion="3.5"` and setup project builds fine.

Comment: This saves me from missing my deadline. Working fine.

Answer (score 5):

This error is related to a dependency error. I removed all references to my primary output project and added them again. It now compiles OK!

Answer (score 4):

I ran up against this issue today. The solution in my case? Restart Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 4):

In my case my solution (VS2008) had a project that was also referenced from another solution (VS2010). In the VS2010 solution I had upgraded the project to .NET 4.0. When I later realized the project was also used in another solution I downgraded it to .NET 3.5. For some reason everything seemed to be changed correctly in the csproj file except one place which is mentioned here: [Error in setup project HRESULT = '80004005'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265805/error-in-setup-project-hresult-80004005)

I know this is already solved somewhere else but I wanted to shed some light on this from another problem angle.

Answer (score 3):

While simply removing and re-adding the project dependencies will work in many cases, it is important to note that:

> The error message  "An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT=80004005."
>   usually happens when project is referenced to  the other project which is
>   not added into the currect [sic] solution. Setup project only supports
>   dependency projects within same solution.[1](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-general/13062/An-error-occurred-while-validating-setup-project)

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

I have spent enormous time on this one myself, though none of the above worked. But I have found another solution with a registry hack, you need to add a new DWORD (`EnableOutOfProcBuild`) value of (`0`) to `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\MSBuild\EnableOutOfProcBuild`

*Note*: this is for Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had installed Visual Studio 2010 alongside Visual Studio 2008. My setup project, when opened in Visual Studio 2008 gave the same error, but was OK in Visual Studio 2010.

If copied to another machine that did not have Visual Studio 2010, but did have Visual Studio 2008, then it would compile.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Visual Studio 2010 and converted the solutions to that version. Because of performance issues I changed my solutions back to Visual Studio 2008. Everything was better now but I got an error when I tried to compile the setup project. I realized that I had a Visual Studio 2010 Test Project in my solution so all I had to do was unload the Test Project and Build the setup project again.

Summary: unload any Visual Studio 2010 project in solution.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I read this answer from another post on Stack Overflow, and it has worked for me.

Open your setup project file (.vdproj) in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) (or any other text editor). Delete these lines at a beginning of the .vdproj file:

```
"SccProjectName" = "8:"
"SccLocalPath" = "8:"
"SccAuxPath" = "8:"
"SccProvider" = "8:"
```

Build again - the error is gone. That error didn't stop me from deploying, building, debugging (or anyting) my project; it just annoyed me. And it came on even if I set all projects to be build in a current configuration and the setup project not to.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old news, but my particular issue and solution are not specifically stated here (as far as I can tell - if I missed it, I apologize).

I had same problem. It would not compile my project, but had no errors. All I could see was "Build Failed". I opened up the "Output" file (Click View--> Output on menu), and it told me exactly which reference (in my case a .dll) was causing the problem.

I deleted and recreated the reference and it changed the reference name from Microsoft.Office.Core (which was appearently only a 32 bit version) to "OFFICE". Then everything worked great. -- Make sure to make a note of the path to the file you are referencing in the properties window... My new path was exactly the same, but the reference name changed anyway.... still scratching my head on that one...

So the moral of the story is... When you get no errors and your build fails, check the "Output" tab and it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had added references to two DLLs that were compiled from NET Framework 4.8 projects, when I changed the main project from NET Framework 4.6 to 4.8 to match, this problem was fixed and the build succeeded.