# Error in setup project HRESULT = '80004005'

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a setup project which has been working fine for months. However, it has suddenly started refusing to build with the error:

> HRESULT = '80004005'

The setup project contains the output from three projects, and I have narrowed down the issue to one of them.

I have found a few questions here with this same issue and have tried them all, namely:

- Removed projects and re-added to the solution
- Removed all references and re-added

If I right click the project output in the setup project and select 'View Dependencies' the list is empty which seems to be a symptom others have found with this issue. However, despite several hours of googling, I have not managed to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - I finally found the answer.  I checked each project file in my solution and found that on of them started with the line

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
```

where all the rest started:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5"
```

I may have opened the project recently in VS2010 however the strange thing is it has worked fine since then.  Anyway, changing the 4.0 to 3.5 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

- *[An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80004005'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/80f30e5c-3872-4ed3-aba6-cc54d5f8922a)*

Comment: I've been through both of those with no success